# The right ISO 8601 format

Tags: time, timezone, iso8601

I am refactoring some code for a Ruby library. This code includes a Date parser.
One of the tests was to parse this string "2008-02-20T8:05:00-010:00" which is supposed to be [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

The previous code would actually output: "Wed Feb 20 18:05:00 UTC 2008".
My new code outputs that: "Wed Feb 20 16:05:00 UTC 2008".

My question is: which one is the right one?

`Time.parse` in Ruby gives the second one. But again, I want to be 100% sure that the previous code AND test were buggy.

Which one is right? (By maybe parsing the string with a library in another language? - I only know Ruby.)

Comment: Is it perhaps due to the timezone implicitly used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct UTC time is 1805.  The time group indicates 0805 in zone -10, so to get UTC add the 10 to the given time.  Thus 1805.  Since 1805 is less than 2400 it's the same day.

If your code is giving 1605, then you almost certainly have the timezone set incorrectly to zone -8, which happens to be Pacific Standard Time.

---

Aha, looks like your input format is messed up.  Observe:

```
irb(main):003:0> Time.parse("2008-02-20T8:05:00-010:00") 
=> Wed Feb 20 08:05:00 -0700 2008
```

I happen to be in zone -7 so it's suiting that to my locale.  But

```
irb(main):004:0> t=Time.parse("2008-02-20T8:05:00-010:00")
=> Wed Feb 20 08:05:00 -0700 2008
irb(main):005:0> t
=> Wed Feb 20 08:05:00 -0700 2008
irb(main):006:0> t.getutc
=> Wed Feb 20 15:05:00 UTC 2008
```

I'm getting an unexpected result.  Now observe:

```
irb(main):007:0> t=Time.parse("2008-02-20T8:05:00-10:00")
=> Wed Feb 20 11:05:00 -0700 2008
irb(main):008:0> t.getutc
=> Wed Feb 20 18:05:00 UTC 2008
```

There's the *expected* result.  See the difference?  First example vs second:

```
irb(main):004:0> t=Time.parse("2008-02-20T8:05:00-010:00")
irb(main):007:0> t=Time.parse("2008-02-20T8:05:00-10:00")
```

I took the spurious extra 0 out (which *I* certainly didn't notice either) and whoosh, it works.

Comment: Yes, I am actually in PST (San Francisco). Does that mean that Ruby's Time.parse fails me?

Comment: No, it means you are getting the time set correctly, but you're outputting it in your local timezone.  Notice that 1805 in zone -10 *is* 1605 in zone -8.

Comment: well, the output is show in UTC both times:
"Wed Feb 20 18:05:00 UTC 2008" 
"Wed Feb 20 16:05:00 UTC 2008"

They can't be right both, can they?

Comment: Try using Time#getutc and see what the Zulu time you're saving is.  Also have a look to make sure you're not calling Time@local somewhere.

Comment: (Thank you for your help... )
I am not sure what you mean by Time@local...

And yes, time.getutc.to_s actually returns "Wed Feb 20 16:05:00 UTC 2008"

Comment: it means I can't type: I meant Time#local.

Comment: So I guess that means the test was actually wrong, since this it was not testing a valid iso8601 format, right?

Comment: That's how it looks.  If you want to actually confirm, get an earlier version of Ruby and try the same experiment.  I'm guessing that a bug in the Ruby stuff was fixed — it got more strict about the ISO format — thereby revealing a misformatted string in your test.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a bunch for the great help! Have a wonderful evening!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is pretty old, but I just ran across it.

I'll bet that something somewhere is interpreting `010` as an *octal* number with the value 8.  Perhaps it's a bug in the implementation of `Time.parse()`?

Comment: This was my first thought as well.  Reading the standard (the wikipedia version: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators) the hour offset is limited to 2 digits; I don't really think 3 would be considered valid, and the fact that it parsed at all should be considered a bug.  Also, 02013 is a valid ISO 8601 notation for the current year, you don't want octal interpretation here.